# WPF SendKeys.SendWait() doesn't work with Visibility=Hidden

Tags: wpf, visibility, hidden

It's all in the title !

The *System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait()* function in **WPF** doesn't work when **Visibility** property of the MainWindow is set to **Hidden**.

What is the problem and how to solve it please?

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms` is not WPF. I wouldn't expect it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WinAPI function

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
```

Ctrl+V example:

```
keybd_event(0x11, 0, 1 | 0, 0);//ctrl down
keybd_event(0x56, 0, 1 | 0, 0);//v down
keybd_event(0x56, 0, 1 | 2, 0);//v up
keybd_event(0x11, 0, 1 | 2, 0);//ctrl up
```

Comment: Windows.Forms.Keys enumeration